# Is there a photo display control available for ipad?

Tags: ipad, photo-gallery

Like a photo gallery control, where you can load and display pictures in thumbnails, and then tap on them, and see full image, zoom in/out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three20 library has a photo viewer that mimics the iPhone's photo viewer:

http://github.com/facebook/three20

Specifically the TTPhotoViewController class.

Comment: You are right. I heard about that one, but heard the drawback is it's big in size too.  Thanks for the link, will take a look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody replied, gonna give my answer, which is no. There is no such control available as of today unfortunately. Also the photos app slider is nice, would like to see some more controls like that.